# VSTS - which process template to pick if primarily interested in kanban, no sprints?

Tags: azure-devops

Will be setting up first VSTS team project and picking the process template, it seems to be down to either agile or scrum.  Reading other posts, it seems scrum is the simpler and for the most part it makes sense for our small team.  However, I do not think we want to use sprints and the "sizing" method for kanban typically uses is more loose also.  My question is if I choose the scrum template, am I forced to use the sprints and if not, can I remove them?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=vsts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/kanban/kanban-basics?view=vsts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "Iterations" is a fundamental part of the work item tracking experience and you cannot change that.

However, there's nothing stopping you from setting up a completely flat iteration structure consisting of only a Backlog iteration with no defined start or end dates, then managing everything from the backlog view in a Kanban fashion.

There is no difference between any of the process templates in this regard, only in the work item names and in some rules around state transitions. I believe Agile has looser rules for state transition, whereas Scrum has stricter rules.